# Rename a column in a list of lists in R

Tags: r, list, rename

I am trying to rename an added "column" to multiple lists that are imbedded in a bigger list.

For example,

```
data<- data.frame(
  ID = c(10,20,20,20,20,30,30), 
  Sales = c(50,40,45,40,40,40,50), 
  Distribution = c(2,4,5,5,4,4,5)
)
```

I first create my list of lists using split.

```
SplitData <- split(data,data$ID)
```

Here is how my data looks like when I call SplitData.

```
‘10’    
Sales 50
Distribution 2

‘20’    
Sales 40,45,40,40   
Distribution 4,5,5,4    

‘30’    
Sales 40,50 
Distribution 4,5
```

Then, I wrote a function to divide two variables within my lists, but I can't seem to figure out how to have `(i[, "Sales"] / i[, "Distribution"])` appear like "AjustedSale".

```
AjustedDis <- function(i){ cbind(i[,],(i[, "Sales"] / i[, "Distribution"]))}
SplitData2 <- lapply(SplitData[1:length(SplitData)], AjustedDis)
```

Here is what happens when I call SplitData2.

```
‘10’
Sales 50
Distribution 2
(i[, "Sales"] / i[, "Distribution"]) 25


‘20’
Sales 40,45,40,40   
Distribution 4,5,5,4    
(i[, "Sales"] / i[, "Distribution"]) 10,9,8,10

‘30’
Sales 40,50 
Distribution 4,5    
(i[, "Sales"] / i[, "Distribution"]) 10,10
```

I have tried this:

```
division<-function(i){(i[, "Sales"] / i[, "DisIndex"])}
AjustedSales<-lapply(SplitData[],division)
AjustedDisV2<-function(i){ cbind(i[,],AjustedSales[,])}
SplitData3<-lapply(SplitData[1:length(SplitData)], AjustedDisV2)
```

but it does not give me what I am expecting.

Comment: Just name the new column in the cbind. For example: `AjustedDis <- function(i){ cbind(i[,],AjustedSale=(i[, "Sales"] / i[, "Distribution"]))}` with your first attempt.

Comment: Also, you might want to look into doing these types of things with `dplyr` for example: `data %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(AdjustedSale=Sales/Distribution)`

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer and the edit @MrFlick. Greatly appreciated!